# Removing vertical line on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following ggplot using the code below. I need to remove the red vertical line on the right. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
ggplot(model.1, aes(x = time, y = activity)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = id), alpha = .3) +
  geom_line(data = data, alpha = .9, size = 1, colour="red4") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),axis.line=element_line(colour="black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())+
  labs(
    x = "Time",
    y = "Activity",
    color = NULL
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try moving the group into the `ggplot` layer:

```
ggplot(model.1,aes(x = time, y = activity, group=id))
```

And remove it from the `geom_line` layer. I had a similar problem, and this got rid of the vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the red vertical line is part of your data, I could be wrong though. If it is you can filter it:

```
filtered_data <- data %>% filter(time < 1)
```

And then use that within the geom_line function.